# Debugging a React Azure Web App

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've got a React app running on Azure. It runs fine in my localhost, however, when I go to the Azure address, it doesn't load; all I get is a blank page with a head and body html element, which is throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The immediate question, of course, is what's causing the error and how do I fix it?

The bigger question in the background is, with a backend app, I can enable logging and look at a log stream and see what's throwing errors in real time. With a frontend app, the errors are happening in my browser; the React Chrome extension doesn't even recognize this as a React app. How do I debug in this context?

Comment: View page source + F12 tools Network tab?

Comment: @evilSnobu that's where I'm seeing the error. It's being ascribed to bundle.js. Not very helpful, eh?

Comment: Is bundle.js being loaded (200 OK)?

Comment: Are you using some kind of webpack/system.js?

Comment: @evilSnobu yes, bundle.js is loading fine.

Comment: @Nick yes, I'm using webpack.

Comment: If you click on the error it should tell you where it's coming from, which file at which line.

Comment: @evilSnobu it says "bundle.js line 1" and leaves it at that.